# Fourier transform of a 3sinc^2(100πt)

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, sampling

I'm currently studying for an exam, and I'm not sure the textbook's answer for  the fourier transform of 3sinc^2(60πt) is correct. For this question, I incorporated the duality property.

Below is my working so far:

[image: sinc]

Our class are given a formula sheet with the following identity which i incorporated into my working along with the duality property:

[image: transform]

From the textbook answers, the answer said the fourier transform of 3sinc^2(60πt) is 1/20*Δ(ω/240π).

The answer looks similar to mine, so I can't be too far off...

Cheers

Comment: Looks like that property (18) which i used was not consistent with the textbook property (Lathi Systems and Signals) which uses the form of sinc as (t/2)sinc^2(wt/4). I will ask the lecturer as soon as possible and follow up with the conclusion if anyone is following...

Comment: It might be easier for you to just take the FT of the sinc function and then convolve the resulting rectangle function it with itself. That way the scaling will naturally fall out of the result and you will not have to rely on inconsistent formulas.